# DISCONNECT / CONNECT to Postgresql via DBeaver script editor?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I want to change connections within my DDL scripts. DBeaver keeps balking. It feels like DBeaver doesn't want me to use CONNECT/DISCONNECT w/in a script?
What am I doing wrong?

```
    DISCONNECT ;
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISCONNECT"
    CONNECT TO mydb USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY postgres;
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CONNECT"
  Position: 1
```

Comment: Typically, you would use `\c` to change databases in a `.sql` script

Comment: ? would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Neither of those are [SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html), so you can't use them.

Comment: Those are ***not*** Postgres SQL commands.